# Counting the number of possibilities

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have given number of `y` string variables. Assignments to these `y` variables can be done in only following:

1. Right hand side of the any `yi` variable is concatenation of `y`'s and `z`'s variables.
2. Number of `z` variables is less than or equals to twice the number of `y` variables.
3. Each `yi` and `zi` can occur at most once on the right hand side. That is `y1 = z1.y1.z2.y2.z3`  and `y2 = y2` is illegal as `y2` occurs twice.
4. No two `y` or `z` variable can't occur consecutively that is `y1 = z1.z2` is not possible. It can be `y1 = z1` only.

So for two `y` variables, `y1` and `y2`, these are the only 11 possibilities:

```
1. y1 = z1.y1.z2
   y2 = z3.y2.z4   (This is same as y1 = y1, y2 = y2 as you can consider z1=z2=z3=z4=epsilon(empty string), y1 = z1.y1 , y2 = z3.y2 and so on)

2. y1 = z1.y2.z2
    y2 = z3.y1.z4

3. y1 = z1.y1.z2.y2.z3
   y2 = z4

4. y1 = z1.y2.z2.y1.z3
   y2 = z4

5. y1 = z1
   y2 = z2.y1.z3.y2.z4

6. y1 = z1
   y2 = z2.y2.z3.y1.z4

7. y1 = z1.y1.z2
   y2 = z3

8. y1 = z1.y2.z2
   y2 = z3

9. y1 = z1
   y2 = z2.y1.z3

10. y1 = z1
     y2 = z2.y2.z3

11. y1 = z1
   y2 = z2
```

I want to calculate number of possible assignments given the number of `y` variables.

Comment: It seems that where it says "consequently" you mean "consecutively"?

Comment: Are permutations among $z_i$ variables not allowed? For example, is $y_1=z_1$, $y_2=z_2$ different from $y_1=z_2$, $y_2=z_1$? Also, is $y_1=y_1 z_1 y_2$, $y_2=z_2$ not allowed? Does the consecutive requirement extend across LHS and RHS?

Comment: y1=z1, y2=z2 is same as y1=z2, y2=z1. And y1=y1z1y2, y2=z2 is same as y1 = z1.y1.z2.y2.z3 ,y2 = z4. LHS can be only single y variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the number of $y$ variables be $n$. Suppose exactly $r$ variables $y_i$ are used in the RHS (over all the assignments). These $r$ can be chosen in $\binom{n}{r}$ ways. Now these $r$ variables can be distributed among the $n$ assignments, with order, in $\frac{(n+r-1)!}{(n-1)!}$ ways. And we can see that once this is done, all the assignments are fixed. So the total number of assignments will be

$$
\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} \frac{(n+r-1)!}{(n-1)!}
$$